# How to read content of one.php and write into two.php

Tags: php

I have one file `one.php`

```
<?php //just a php function doen't have to do any thing with the question
function B(){

}
?>
```

Through php I want to read `one.php` as it is and write into `two.php` as it is..
**Note**- `'<'` getting converted into `'$lt;'`

Answer to it is

```
<?php
    $text = file_get_contents("one.php");
    file_put_contents("two.php", $text);
?>
```

Now further what I want is add one more php function say `function A(){}` to the content of `one.php` and write it into `two.php`

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: replace "``$file`` = file_get_contents()" with ``$theData`` = file_get_contents() will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fairly simple nowadays :-).

```
$text = file_get_contents("one.php");
file_put_contents("two.php", $text);
```

For more parameters to the methods, see the PHP.net documentation on [file-get-contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file-put-contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: I got it.....
Thats working...
Can you please help me out with one more thing ...
How do I append one more function into it like `<?php function A(){} //read from one.php function B(){} //appended function?>`

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you are asking about, do you want to put the two function calls in separate methods? Please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are after an exact copy of "one.php", then use PHP's "[copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)" method.

```
copy('one.php', 'two.php');
```

In regards to your edited question, the solution is:

```
$content = file_get_contents('one.php');
$content .= 'function A() {}';
file_put_contents('two.php', $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: See my answer, with include you could create any function in one.php and use it in two.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$contents = file_get_contents('one.php');
$newContents = htmlspecialchars ($contents);
file_put_contents('two.php', $newContents);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are mixing up strings and resources a little bit. file_get_contents() stores the page in a string. It's easier to use file_put_contents in that case.

```
<?php
file_put_contents("two.php", htmlspecialchars (file_get_contents('one.php')));
// file_get_contents(): Stores the content of one.php into a string
// htmlspecialchars: encodes html
// file_put_contents(): Writes the string into two.php
?>
```

In your case, an even easier solution would be:

```
<?php
include("one.php");
?>
```